# How to rotate sprite in sprite kit with swift

Tags: ios, rotation, sprite-kit, swift, ios8

Hi my problem is regarding the rotation of two sprites. When I touch the right half of the screen the rotation starts and moving sprite2 and sprite3. If I touch the left half of the screen the rotation stops because velocity-velocity = 0. If I touch the left half again the rotation begins.

However, if I touch the half of the screen corresponding with the current rotational-direction the velocity is duplicated. I want to be able to change the direction of the rotation, but for the speed to remain constant.

Video demonstrating the problem: http://youtu.be/HxLwl1QZiNM

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bWhite")
    let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bBlue")
    let sprite3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bRed")
    let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bCircle")       

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        backColor = SKColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        self.backgroundColor = backColor

        sprite.setScale(1.25)
        sprite2.setScale(1)
        sprite3.setScale(1)
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, (self.frame.size.height/2)-200);
        circle.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, (self.frame.size.height/2)-200);
        sprite3.zRotation = 172.77
        sprite2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-1.10, 0.5);
        sprite3.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-1.10, 0.5);

        self.addChild(sprite)
        self.addChild(circle)
        sprite.addChild(sprite2)
        sprite.addChild(sprite3)
    }

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)
            let action2 = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-M_PI), duration:1)

            if (location.x > self.frame.size.width / 2)
            {
                sprite2.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action2))
                sprite3.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action2))
            } else {
                sprite2.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
                sprite3.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
            }     
        }
    }
```

Comment: So to see if I've understood you correctly: You want the circles to _begin_ rotating in the direction indicated by the initial touch. After this you only want to be able to switch the orientation, not stop it completely?

Comment: thats exactly what I want

Comment: I want to move while I'm touching left half of screen rotate to left, If I don't touch stop and if I touch right half of screen rotate to right

Comment: Sorry, do you want to move in addition to the rotation or are you referring to the fact that you want to trigger the rotation based on the position of the touch?

Comment: If i touch left half of screen rotate to left if stop touching left stop de rotation, no move .If i touch right half of screen rotate to right if stop touching right stop de rotation, no move.

Comment: I believe my updated code below achieves just this. :-)

Comment: @nickfalk Hey, I've got a question about your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410893/swift-spritekit-gradually-increase-rotation, if you could help me out that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, take three. I'm not 100% sure about the specifics of when the rotation should end etc. but all the pieces should be in place with the below code.  It will:

- start rotation clockwise or counterclockwise based on the position of the first touch
- stop the rotation if the user touches for the same direction again
- switch the rotation if the user touches on the other half of the screen

  ```
    import SpriteKit  

    enum rotationDirection{
         case clockwise
         case counterClockwise
         case none
     } 

    class GameScene: SKScene {
      var currentRotationDirection = rotationDirection.none
      let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))

      override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
        sprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(sprite)
      }

      override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch : UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        let touchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let newRotationDirection : rotationDirection = touchPosition.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) ? .clockwise : .counterClockwise

        if currentRotationDirection != newRotationDirection && currentRotationDirection != .none{
          reverseRotation()
          currentRotationDirection = newRotationDirection
        } else if currentRotationDirection == newRotationDirection{
          stopRotation()
          currentRotationDirection = .none
        } else if (currentRotationDirection == .none){
        setupRotationWith(direction: newRotationDirection)
        currentRotationDirection = newRotationDirection
        }
      }

      func reverseRotation(){
        let oldRotateAction = sprite.actionForKey("rotate")
        let newRotateAction = SKAction.reversedAction(oldRotateAction)
        sprite.runAction(newRotateAction(), withKey: "rotate")
      }

      func stopRotation(){
        sprite.removeActionForKey("rotate")
      }

      func setupRotationWith(#direction: rotationDirection){
        let angle : Float = (direction == .clockwise) ? Float(M_PI) : -Float(M_PI)
        let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(angle, duration: 1)
        let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotate)
        sprite.runAction(repeatAction, withKey: "rotate")
      }
    }
  ```

---

Edit: Changed example to cater the specific needs in the question. Something odd with the code formatting not quite sure what's going on there.

Comment: yeah it works you are the best, but I want to move while I'm touching left half of screen rotate to left, If I don't touch stop and if I touch right half of screen rotate to right

Comment: If i touch left half of screen rotate to left if stop touching left stop de rotation, no move .If i touch right half of screen rotate to right if stop touching right stop de rotation, no move.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve: Do you want the rotation to STOP if you touch a second time on the same half of the screen? Or do you want the rotation to stop when touching the opposite side?

Comment: the rotation should end If I lift my finger from the screen

Comment: OK, then you need to remove the `else if currentRotationDirection == newRotationDirection` and implement `currentRotationDirection = .none` and call the `stopRotation()` function in `touchesEnded`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing all current actions before adding new, since they may conflict.  I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tired removing the actions at touchesEnded? I had a similar problem before where I wanted my object to move left to right based on which half of the screen the user touched. I had a similar issue where if I touched right and right again my velocity would double, and if I touched left my object would just stop.

I fixed this issue by adding the touchesEnded method and just removed the actions whenever I let go. This essentially reset my move action so the object would stop when I let go and would go to the opposite direction right away instead of having to tap it twice.