# Swift SpriteKit - Gradually increase rotation

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm experimenting round with @nickfalk's answer on [How to rotate sprite in sprite kit with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239271/how-to-rotate-sprite-in-sprite-kit-with-swift) on how to rotate a sprite in sprite kit.

How would I adjust this to gradually increase rotation speed up to a maximum, then when the screen is clicked, it gradually slows down and goes in the reverse direction for x amount of time?

Thanks!

Toby.

Comment: Well, how do you want it to happen? Over time, so that like after 10s it increases by .1 or something? If not over time you could increase the speed in some `update()` method by some value.

Comment: I'm trying to make it similar to this http://terrycavanaghgames.com/maverickbird/

The player gray square, on touch, slows down rotation then speeds up to a maximum.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get past the 2 so... :D

Comment: Haha, well basically every time you tap the screen, the square starts slowing down quickly, then speeds up the rotation speed again to its original value.
Keep at it ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able grasp the details of what you're after: Do you want the rotation-speed to increase automatically or on each tap?

Comment: @nickfalk Rotation speed is constant. On tap, rotation slows down and stops, then rotation speeds up to its original constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the following (slightly messy proof of concept) spins a sprite at a constant speed. Upon tap+hold it gradually slows the rotation to a halt. Ending the touch immediately returns the rotation to full speed.

I've set up a scene with the following properties: `var sprite : SKSpriteNode?` and `var shouldDecelerate = false`:

The sprite is set up with the preferred details and have a repeactActionForever-action running a 360 degrees rotation. From here its fairly straightforward:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    shouldDecelerate = true
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    shouldDecelerate = false
    sprite?.speed = 1
    sprite!.runAction(SKAction.speedTo(sprite!.speed, duration: 1/60))
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if let sprite = sprite {
        if sprite.speed > 0 && shouldDecelerate {
            let newSpeed = max(sprite.speed - 0.1, 0) // we don't want a negative speed as it will reverse the rotation
            sprite.runAction(SKAction.speedTo(newSpeed, duration: 1/60))
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a gradual increase in speed you basically just need an if with opposite logic of the one I've included in `update()` above, oh and you should also remove the `sprite?.speed = 1` line in `touchesEnded()`.

If you need to have other move-actions where the speed is not effected by the rotation-speed I suggest you hook the sprite up to an SKNode and let this handle the other actions.

Comment: Thanks for this, besides the components you've provided, is there any more code that I need? I can't seem to get it to work. Sorry, I'm new to iOS development. Thanks again!

Comment: If you create a fresh SpriteKit game and chuck the above into the GameScene (including the properties mentioned outside the code) you should be good to go. You need to create the sprite instance somewhere of course...

Comment: Okay I have it now. Thanks a lot, appreciate your time, I'll post again if I have any further questions

Comment: No worries, please not though that while the above works fine you should probably rethink how you want to organize this if you're doing more than just throwing some code together for the fun of it...

Comment: Yeah there's some additions I want to make, but you've taught me that I can use .speedTo, which I was unaware of, and will come in handy.